# Dynamic call to message bundles?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, resourcebundle

I have a very simple JSF 2.0 project.

I have an index.xhtml file to show me a picture of Mount Rushmore.
On this page, I can click on the picture and I want it to go to "president.xhtml" - no problem in that. A simple action=""...

My problem is that my message bundle file (messages.properties) is set up with static keys and values, ex.:

```
jeffersonPageTitle=Thomas Jefferson
rooseveltPageTitle=Theodore Roosevelt
lincolnPageTitle=Abraham Lincoln
washingtonPageTitle=George Washington
```

And in my "president.xhtml" file, I want it to show these titles depending on what I clicked on.

```
<h:form>
  <span class="presidentPageTitle">#{msgs['rushmore.president'],PageTitle}</span>
  <br />
  <h:graphicImage library="images" name="jefferson.jpg" styleClass="leftImage" />
  <span class="presidentDiscussion">#{msgs.washingtonDiscussion}</span>
  <br />
  <h:commandLink action="index" styleClass="backLink">${msgs.indexLinkText}</h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Second line in the code above is my problem - I don't know how to refer to the get-Method in my java-code. Code is here:

```
@ManagedBean // or @Named
@RequestScoped
public class Rushmore {
 private String outcome = null;
 private Rectangle washingtonRect = new Rectangle(70, 30, 40, 40);
 private Rectangle jeffersonRect = new Rectangle(115, 45, 40, 40);
 private Rectangle rooseveltRect = new Rectangle(135, 65, 40, 40);
 private Rectangle lincolnRect = new Rectangle(175, 62, 40, 40);

 public Rushmore() {}

 public void handleMouseClick(ActionEvent e) {
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  String clientId = e.getComponent().getClientId(context);
  Map<String, String> requestParams = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();


  int x = new Integer((String) requestParams.get(clientId + ".x")).intValue();
  int y = new Integer((String) requestParams.get(clientId + ".y")).intValue();

  outcome = null;

  if (washingtonRect.contains(new Point(x, y))) {
   outcome = "washington";
  }

  if (jeffersonRect.contains(new Point(x, y))) {
   outcome = "jefferson";
  }

  if (rooseveltRect.contains(new Point(x, y))) {
   outcome = "roosevelt";
  }
  if (lincolnRect.contains(new Point(x, y))) {
   outcome = "lincoln";
  }
  System.out.println(requestParams.keySet());
 }

 public String getPresident() {
  return outcome;
 }

 public String navigate() {
  if(outcome != null) {
   return "president";
  }
  else return null;
 }
}
```

It's the getPresident method I'm trying to reach in the president.xhtml file...

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the difference from the example you are following?  IIRC it is one of Cay Horstmanns examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`c:set`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/set.html).

```
<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl" ...>
...
<c:set var="pageTitle" value="#{rushmore.president}PageTitle" />
<span class="presidentPageTitle">#{msgs[pageTitle]}</span>
```